# Python and LXML: extremely slow, more efficient code?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm processing XML documents like the following.

```
<tok lemma="i" xpos="CC">e</tok> 
<tok lemma="que" xpos="CS">que</tok> 
<tok lemma="aquey" xpos="PD0MP0">aqueys</tok> 
<tok lemma="marit" xpos="NCMP000">marits</tok> 
<tok lemma="estar" xpos="VMIP3P0">stiguen</tok>  
[...]
<tok lemma="habitar" xpos="VMIP3P0">habiten</tok> 
<tok lemma="en" xpos="SPS00">en</tok>
<tok lemma="aquex" xpos="PD0FS0">aqueix</tok> 
<tok lemma="terra" xpos="NCMS000">món</tok>
[...]
<tok lemma="viure" xpos="VMIP3P0">viuen</tok> 
<tok lemma="en" xpos="SPS00">en</tok>
<tok lemma="aquex" xpos="PD0FP0">aqueixes</tok> 
<tok lemma="casa" xpos="NCFP000">cases</tok>
```

I'm using the following code to change the attributes of certain elements whenever certain conditions are met. The code works as expected and I'm getting the output I want. However the time it takes to process all the files seems way too much. If you notice, I have some print statements that allow me to monitor the whole process. Sometimes it takes 5 minutes or more between two prints.

In fact, I've had to kill the process because it was taking too long. I know it is working fine because the output files that I get are correctly modified and when I did a test with a much smaller number of files the whole process managed to run to its end without a glitch (although taking forever to finish).

I have one of the new macs with the M1 max silicon chip so I thought this would go a lot faster. It is just as slow with the Intel chip. Is this normal when using LXML or being a novice I'm just producing very inefficient code? Is there any way to make this kind of thing faster?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import os
import lxml.etree as et

#ROOT = '/Users/josepm.fontana/Downloads/_POTI'
ROOT = '/Users/josepm.fontana/Downloads/CICA_TESTIN'
ext = ('.xml')


def xml_change(root_element):

    for el in root.xpath('//tok[following-sibling::tok[1][re:match(@xpos, "^N")]]', 
        namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"}):
        if el.text == 'aquest' or el.text == 'Aquest' or el.text == 'AQUEST' or el.text == 'aqueix' or el.text == 'Aqueix' or el.text == 'AQUEIX':

            print(el.text)
            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MS0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquest')


        if el.text == 'aquel' or el.text == 'Aquel' or el.text == 'AQUEL' or el.text == 'aquell' or el.text == 'Aquell' or el.text == 'AQUELL':

            print(el.text)
            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MS0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquell')

                     

        if el.text == 'aquests' or el.text == 'Aquests' or el.text == 'AQUESTS':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MP0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquest')

        if el.text == 'aquells' or el.text == 'Aquells' or el.text == 'AQUELLS' or el.text == 'aqueys' or el.text == 'Aqueys'  or el.text == 'AQUEYS' or el.text == 'aqueyls'  or el.text == 'Aqueyls'  or el.text == 'AQUEYLS' or el.text == 'aqueys'  or el.text == 'Aqueys'  or el.text == 'AQUEYS':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MP0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquell')

        if el.text == 'aquestas' or el.text == 'Aquestas' or el.text == 'AQUESTAS' or el.text == 'aqueixes' or el.text == 'Aqueixes' or el.text == 'AQUEIXES':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0FP0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquest')
        
        if el.text == 'aqualas' or el.text == 'Aqualas' or el.text == 'AQUALAS' or el.text == 'aquelas' or el.text == 'Aquelas' or el.text == 'AQUELAS' or el.text == 'aqueles' or el.text == 'Aqueles' or el.text == 'AQUELES' or el.text == 'aquellas' or el.text == 'Aquellas' or el.text == 'AQUELLAS' or el.text == 'aquelles' or el.text == 'Aquelles' or el.text == 'AQUELLES':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0FP0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquell')


# iterate all dirs
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):

    # iterate all files
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(ext):
            # join root dir and file name
            file_path = os.path.join(ROOT, file)

            # load root element from file
            root = et.parse(file_path).getroot()

            # recursively change  elements from xml
            xml_change(root)
    
        

            # init tree object from root
            tree = et.ElementTree(root)

            # save cleaned xml tree object to file. Important to specify encoding
                
            tree.write(file_path.replace('.xml', '-clean.xml'), encoding='utf-8', doctype='<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "estcorpus.dtd">', xml_declaration=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is evaluating all conditions while only one would be met each time. One possible optimization is to make them if-elseif

```
    if el.text == 'aquest' or el.text == 'Aquest' or el.text == 'AQUEST' or el.text == 'aqueix' or el.text == 'Aqueix' or el.text == 'AQUEIX':

        print(el.text)
        print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
        el.set('xpos', 'DD0MS0')
        el.set('lemma', 'aquest')
    else if el.text == 'aquel' or el.text == 'Aquel' or el.text == 'AQUEL' or el.text == 'aquell' or el.text == 'Aquell' or el.text == 'AQUELL':
        print(el.text)
        print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
        el.set('xpos', 'DD0MS0')
        el.set('lemma', 'aquell')
    # other else if here
```

Also, plain XPath could be used to avoid regular expressions

```
//tok[following-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, "N")]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @LMC. Alas, I'm unable to test whether this goes faster because I'm getting an error:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  ..., line 79, in <module>
    xml_change(root)
 [...], line 15, in xml_change
    for el in root.xpath('//tok[following-sibling::tok[1][@xpos, starts-with("N")]]'):        
  [...]
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
**lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate**
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory

Comment: OK, I think I got it. The problem was with the Xpath syntax. I checked and I think it should be:

**//tok[following-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, "N")]]')**

At least this seems to be working for me. It hasn't finished processing all the documents but it is clearly going much faster.

Comment: Nice. Fixed the xpath in the answer. You can accept it or upvote if you wish.

Comment: Thank you @LMC. I was going to accept the answer and close this but the process crashed without finishing. I don't know whether it is a problem with the code as I didn't get any clear error message. At some point it just stopped processing more documents and it simple threw the error **"fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory"** . I'm hesitant to accept it as it is because I wouldn't want to create problems for other people. I've done searches for this error but I haven't been able to find any useful info.

Comment: Take a look at the stack trace to get the line were the error happens. Doesn't seems to be related to xpath or xml parsing. Also, try with an smaller set of files.

Comment: I ran it on a different computer and I didn't have any problems. As you said, it's clear that whatever the problem is is not related to the xpath or xml parsing. Again, thanks  very much for your help.

Comment: Your answer was indeed correct and helpful in that it improved the speed of the process. 

After fixing some of the problems I was having, though, I ran the program in production with 395 xml documents I have to modify. I'm still waiting for the process to end. Everything seems to be fine. The output files have been properly modified.

I feel there is something that is not quite right, though. It's been around 30 hours and I think this shouldn't be taking this long; sometimes around 6 hours for a new output file to be created. Should I post a new version of this question?

Comment: [Profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) the script could help to know what's slowing down the process. Are production files different than those used for dev (bigger, etc.)? Is it writing/reading over a network share? You should reproduce the scenario as close as possible. `strace` could give an idea of what's the process doing also.