# Processing of XML files excruciatingly slow with LXML Python

Tags: python, xml, nlp, lxml, text-processing

I'm processing XML documents like the following.

```
<tok id="w-1626" ord="16" lemma="i" xpos="CC">e</tok> 
<tok id="w-1627" ord="17" lemma="que" xpos="CS">que</tok> 
<tok id="w-1628" ord="18" lemma="aquey" xpos="PD0MP0">aqueys</tok> 
<tok id="w-1629" ord="19" lemma="marit" xpos="NCMP000">marits</tok> 
<tok id="w-1630" ord="20" lemma="estar" xpos="VMIP3P0">stiguen</tok>  
[...]
<tok id="w-2000" ord="10" lemma="habitar" xpos="VMIP3P0">habiten</tok> 
<tok id="w-2001" ord="10" lemma="en" xpos="SPS00">en</tok>
<tok id="w-2002" ord="11" lemma="aquex" xpos="PD0FS0">aqueix</tok> 
<tok id="w-2003" ord="12" lemma="terra" xpos="NCMS000">món</tok>
[...]
<tok id="w-2030" ord="18" lemma="viure" xpos="VMIP3P0">viuen</tok> 
<tok id="w-2031" ord="19" lemma="en" xpos="SPS00">en</tok>
<tok id="w-2032" ord="20" lemma="aquex" xpos="PD0FP0">aqueixes</tok> 
<tok id="w-2033" ord="21" lemma="casa" xpos="NCFP000">cases</tok>
```

I need to change the attributes of certain elements whenever certain conditions are met. With the help of @LMC (see: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545510/python-and-lxml-extremely-slow-more-efficient-code/73545789](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545510/python-and-lxml-extremely-slow-more-efficient-code/73545789?noredirect=1#comment129875845_73545789))I optimized the initial code I had to proces the xml files. Here's an exact copy of the code I'm using now.

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
import lxml.etree as et


ROOT = '/Path-to-input-xml-files'
ext = ('.xml')


def xml_change(root_element):


    for el in root.xpath('//tok[following-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, "N")]]'):        
                          
        if el.text == 'aquest' or el.text == 'Aquest' or el.text == 'AQUEST' or el.text == 'aquast' or el.text == 'Aquast' or el.text == 'AQUAST' or el.text == 'aqast' or el.text == 'Aqast' or el.text == 'AQAST' or el.text == 'aqax' or el.text == 'Aqax' or el.text == 'AQAX' or el.text == 'aqest' or el.text == 'Aqest' or el.text == 'AQEST' or el.text == 'aqet' or el.text == 'Aqet' or el.text == 'AQET' or el.text == 'aquet' or el.text == 'Aquet' or el.text == 'AQUET':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MS0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquest')



        elif el.text == 'aquel' or el.text == 'Aquel' or el.text == 'AQUEL' or el.text == 'aquell' or el.text == 'Aquell' or el.text == 'AQUELL' or el.text == 'aqal' or el.text == 'Aqal' or el.text == 'AQAL' or el.text == 'aqual' or el.text == 'Aqual' or el.text == 'AQUAL' or el.text == 'aqueyl' or el.text == 'Aqueyl' or el.text == 'AQUEYL' or el.text == 'aqueil' or el.text == 'Aqueil' or el.text == 'AQUEIL':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MS0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquell')
       

        elif el.text == 'aquests' or el.text == 'Aquests' or el.text == 'AQUESTS' or el.text == 'aquets' or el.text == 'Aquets' or el.text == 'AQUETS' or el.text == 'aquetz' or el.text == 'Aquetz' or el.text == 'AQUETZ':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MP0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquest')

        elif el.text == 'aquells' or el.text == 'Aquells' or el.text == 'AQUELLS' or el.text == 'aqueys' or el.text == 'Aqueys'  or el.text == 'AQUEYS' or el.text == 'aqueyls'  or el.text == 'Aqueyls'  or el.text == 'AQUEYLS':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MP0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquell')

        elif el.text == 'aquestas' or el.text == 'Aquestas' or el.text == 'AQUESTAS' or el.text == 'aquestes' or el.text == 'Aquestes' or el.text == 'AQUESTES' or el.text == 'aquetes' or el.text == 'Aquetes' or el.text == 'AQUETES' or el.text == 'aquastes' or el.text == 'Aquastes' or el.text == 'AQUASTES' or el.text == 'aquastas' or el.text == 'Aquastas' or el.text == 'AQUASTAS'  or el.text == 'aqastas' or el.text == 'Aqastas' or el.text == 'AQASTAS' or el.text == 'aquexas' or el.text == 'Aquexas' or el.text == 'AQUEXAS':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0FP0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquest')
        
        elif el.text == 'aqualas' or el.text == 'Aqualas' or el.text == 'AQUALAS' or el.text == 'aquelas' or el.text == 'Aquelas' or el.text == 'AQUELAS' or el.text == 'aqueles' or el.text == 'Aqueles' or el.text == 'AQUELES' or el.text == 'aquellas' or el.text == 'Aquellas' or el.text == 'AQUELLAS' or el.text == 'aquelles' or el.text == 'Aquelles' or el.text == 'AQUELLES' or el.text == 'aquales' or el.text == 'Aquales' or el.text == 'AQUALES' or el.text == 'aqueylas' or el.text == 'Aqueylas' or el.text == 'AQUEYLAS' or el.text == 'aqueyles' or el.text == 'Aqueyles' or el.text == 'AQUEYLES':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0FP0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquell')

        elif el.text == 'aquesta' or el.text == 'Aquesta' or el.text == 'AQUESTA' or el.text == 'aquasta' or el.text == 'Aquasta' or el.text == 'AQUASTA' or el.text == 'aquaste' or el.text == 'Aquaste' or el.text == 'AQUASTE' or el.text == 'aqasta' or el.text == 'Aqasta' or el.text == 'AQASTA' or el.text == 'aquetes' or el.text == 'aqaste' or el.text == 'Aqaste' or el.text == 'AQASTE' or el.text == 'aquaxa' or el.text == 'Aquaxa' or el.text == 'AQUAXA' or el.text == 'aqexa' or el.text == 'Aqexa'  or el.text == 'AQEXA' or el.text == 'aquexa' or el.text == 'Aquexa' or el.text == 'AQUEXA':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0FS0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquest')

        elif el.text == 'aquala' or el.text == 'Aquala' or el.text == 'AQUALA' or el.text == 'aquale' or el.text == 'Aquale' or el.text == 'AQUALE'  or el.text == 'aquela' or el.text == 'Aquela' or el.text == 'AQUELA' or el.text == 'aqueyla' or el.text == 'Aqueyla' or el.text == 'AQUEYLA' or el.text == 'aqueila' or el.text == 'Aqueila' or el.text == 'AQUEILA':

            print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos'))
            el.set('xpos', 'DD0FS0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquell')
# iterate all dirs
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):

    # iterate all files
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(ext):
            # join root dir and file name
            file_path = os.path.join(ROOT, file)

            # load root element from file
            root = et.parse(file_path).getroot()

            # recursively change  elements from xml
            xml_change(root)
    
        

            # init tree object from root
            tree = et.ElementTree(root)

            # save cleaned xml tree object to file. Important to specify encoding
                
            tree.write(file_path.replace('.xml', '-clean.xml'), encoding='utf-8', doctype='<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "estcorpus.dtd">', xml_declaration=True)
```

@LMC's advice was indeed useful and with a test run involving a few xml documents to process I noticed that the optimization resulted in a slight increase of speed. I think, however, that there is something fundamentally wrong with what I'm doing because it's been already 38 hours and the process still has not finished. Granted, there are a lot of conditions that have to be checked and processing these kinds of texts documents is supposed to be slow. But 38 hours and counting on a pretty powerful computer (Mac Studio with M1 max chip)? I have never experienced something like this.

I provide some more information that could be useful to people who have some experience working on similar projects. The total amount of XML documents I'm processing is 395 with a total size of 585 MB. The largest document is 34MB and the smallest is 3KB but most documents are between 100KB and 4MB.

Now, here's the odd thing. The speed of the process does not seem to be related to the length of the processed documents. It is as if the processing is done in bursts. All of a sudden I get a bunch of print statements (from   `print('Current value is:', el.get('lemma'), el.get('xpos')))` indicating that matches are found and a bunch of output documents of different sizes are generated.

However, after that a lot of hours can go by without any new print statements or output documents being generated. Here are a couple of screenshots of the directory where the output files are created so that you can see the time gaps between the creation of new files.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I cannot see much of a correlation between the size of the files and the times it takes to process them. At any rate, even if the file is large, it seems to me that 17 hours to process a single file is a bit too much. What do you think? Am I wrong and this is what should be expected with these kinds of jobs or there is something I'm doing wrong? Is there anything I could do to make this faster?

**UPDATE:**

OK, in the end I incorporated the changes suggested by @LMC. The reduction in the time it takes to process the large files is considerable. I've done some testing and I feel pretty confident the increase in processing speed can be attributed mainly to adding       the parameter 'remove_blank_text=True' in the parsing part of the process. As I noticed in the comments, changing the XPath syntax as per @LMC suggestion also helps but this change is much more noticeable.

Here's the new code in case someone can benefit from having a look at it and comparing it to the initial one:

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
import lxml.etree as et

ROOT = '/Users/josepm.fontana/Downloads/CICA_TESTIN'
ext = ('.xml')


def xml_change(root_element):

    for el in root_element.xpath('//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "N")]/preceding-sibling::tok[1]'):    
        doc_counter = doc_counter + 1

        if el.text == 'aquest' or el.text == 'Aquest' or el.text == 'AQUEST' or el.text == 'aquast' or el.text == 'Aquast' or el.text == 'AQUAST' or el.text == 'aqast' or el.text == 'Aqast' or el.text == 'AQAST' or el.text == 'aqax' or el.text == 'Aqax' or el.text == 'AQAX' or el.text == 'aqest' or el.text == 'Aqest' or el.text == 'AQEST' or el.text == 'aqet' or el.text == 'Aqet' or el.text == 'AQET' or el.text == 'aquet' or el.text == 'Aquet' or el.text == 'AQUET' or el.text == 'aqueix' or el.text == 'Aqueix' or el.text == 'AQUEIX' or el.text == 'aquex' or el.text == 'Aquex' or el.text == 'AQUEX':

            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MS0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquest')

        elif el.text == 'aquel' or el.text == 'Aquel' or el.text == 'AQUEL' or el.text == 'aquell' or el.text == 'Aquell' or el.text == 'AQUELL' or el.text == 'aqal' or el.text == 'Aqal' or el.text == 'AQAL' or el.text == 'aqual' or el.text == 'Aqual' or el.text == 'AQUAL' or el.text == 'aqueyl' or el.text == 'Aqueyl' or el.text == 'AQUEYL' or el.text == 'aqueil' or el.text == 'Aqueil' or el.text == 'AQUEIL':

            el.set('xpos', 'DD0MS0')
            el.set('lemma', 'aquell')
       
        #[...] 6 more elif lines with similar lengths and contents [...]

# iterate all dirs
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):

    # iterate all files
    for file in files:
        
        if file.endswith(ext):
            startFileProcessTime = time.perf_counter()
            
            # join root dir and file name
            file_path = os.path.join(ROOT, file)

           # load root element from file
            parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
            file_root = et.parse(file_path, parser).getroot()
           
            xml_change(file_root)

            # init tree object from file_root
            tree = et.ElementTree(file_root)

            # save cleaned xml tree object to file with a new name. Important to specify encoding
                
            tree.write(file_path.replace('.xml', '-clean.xml'), encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True, doctype='<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "estcorpus.dtd">', xml_declaration=True)
```

As things stand, however, I am not sure whether I should consider this issue closed and, therefore, the question answered. In my last test an XML document with 34,3MB took 1 hour and 16 minutes to process. One with 11MB took only 1.5 minutes. Definitely not proportional.

The improvement is huge. Before the optimization of the code, the same document with 34,3MB took almost a whole day to process. For me this is already quite manageable. Yet, I have the feeling that 1 hour and 16 minutes is still too long.

I tried with 'iterparse' but I wasn't able to get it to work. It turns out it is not compatible with XPath and I wanted to be able to leverage the little I've learned about XPath syntax. I feel starting a new thread as to how to change this code to make it work with 'iterparse' would confuse things so I'll leave this as is. I'd like it to remain essentially about how efficient you can get with LXML and XPath. I didn't try SaxonC in the end, either. I ran into some problems with the installation and I got frustrated so I left it for some other time. I need to continue with my project so this is where I got to.

I'll wait to see whether somebody with more experience intervenes and let us know whether this is the most one could expect and then close it.

Comment: Worth trying `//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "N")]/preceding-sibling::tok[1]` if it gives same results.

Comment: Thanks again LMC. I must confess I was a bit skeptical that what you suggested would make a difference but it does.    

I'll add more information in my comment to @Michael Kay but here's the info that's relevant to your contribution:    

With 10 xml docs, total size 19MB):  

//tok[following-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, "N")]]  

➝ First attempt: 33 minutes to process (381.7439 secs)  
➝ Second attempt: 23 m. (1381.7055 secs)  
  
  
//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "N")]/preceding-sibling::tok[1]  
➝ 1st: 6m (381.7439secs)  
➝ 2nd: 4m (237.6536secs)

Comment: With //tok[starts-with(@xpos, "N")]/preceding-sibling::tok[1] the largest xml doc (10,8MB) took 3 and 5.8 minutes to process (i.e. almost the entire time it took for all the 10xml docs to process).  

With //tok[following-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, "N")]] it took 30 and 21 minutes respectively in the two tries (pretty close to the time it took to process all the documents).  

Second largest document: 4MB. It took 18 and 27 seconds with your syntax; 91 and 125 seconds with the original syntax.  

No idea why there are such considerable differences in the different tries.

Comment: While once again your suggestions did indeed make this code substantially more efficient, the biggest problem still remains. I have the feeling that this is still too much time to process files of these sizes. The larger doc I have to process is 34MB. When I try processing this one it still takes forever. I've had to stop the process because last time it took almost an entire day. Even if it would take a third of that with the improved syntax, it is still too long, don't you think? So now I have to figure out how to use profiling. Does anybody have any recommendation for a particular library?

Comment: Also, if you have time, I'd be really interested in knowing why it should make so much of a difference using //tok[starts-with(@xpos, "N")]/preceding-sibling::tok[1] instead of //tok[following-sibling::tok[1][starts-with(@xpos, "N")]]

Comment: I think the difference is in the parser optimizations while searching, `//tok[...]` might get all elements then check the condition. `//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "N")]` gets specific nodes then blindly get the preceding-sibling

Comment: Thanks again @LMC. As I said, it does make a big difference. As I will comment on your answer, the other suggestions you make (above all remove_blank_text in the parser) also make a huge difference.

Comment: As there is some `<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "estcorpus.dtd">` mentioned, are these local DTD files? Any chance they are referencing/including external DTDs on the web, in particular like the W3C ones, where such requests then hang for a long time (as e.g. the W3C doesn't want to handle all request to the XHTML DTD but expects you to use a catalog or to cache a local copy)?

Comment: Thanks @Martin. Somebody who knows more than me will correct me if I'm wrong but I think this reference to an (indeed external) DTC is not checked during the process. In fact, I had to add this string myself together with the encoding to the part of the code where it appears because otherwise the newly created file (in tree.write(file_path.replace(...) would not contain these headings that were part of the original. They are not part of the root and lxml.etree ignores them so they have to be added again. So I don't think this is the reason why the process is so slow.

Answer (score 1):

There's something pathological going on here, there's no way it should take this long. Things I would try to isolate the cause:

(a) see if there is any network traffic generated.

(b) take a look at memory consumption to see if there's excessive paging or garbage collection

(c) reduce the processing you're doing on each document to something trivial to see if the problem is with parsing/saving the documents, or with the processing you are doing on each document.

**UPDATE**

Looking at the comments since I wrote this answer you seem to be making good progress in eliminating some possible causes and homing in on issues where a small change makes a big difference. It does look to me from reading the thread that you've got some XPath navigation with quadratic performance that's blowing up on large documents. I don't know the XPath processor you're using and it might well depend on fine details of exactly what it optimizes and what it doesn't. I find it surprising that this XPath expression should have non-linear performance. I'd be inclined to suggest trying it with SaxonC, which also has a Python API [disclaimer, that's my company's product].

Comment: Thanks @Michael  

Sorry it's taken me a while to answer. I'm pretty new in this and I've had to do some research before I tried your suggestions. Still not done, I'm afraid. I'm a bit stuck with determining whether there's excessive paging or garbage collection. I've tried some profilers but I'm not sure I'm doing this right. Anyway, I can address at least two of your points:

Comment: (a) I'm not sure I'm understanding you properly but all of the files are being processed and saved locally. So, in principle, the execution of the code should not generate any network traffic, right?  

(c) Done that. I've used the Time module and introduced some counters in the code. Saving the docs is not the problem.  

 file_root = et.parse(file_path).getroot() is also not the problem. It takes very little for all the docs involved. Where it gets stuck (the larger the files, though not directly proportionally) is in the execution of:
xml_change(file_root)
But see comment to LMC

Comment: Thanks for the update @Michael. LMC made other very good recommendations that have improved things quite a bit and reduced the processing time considerably. Nevertheless, I think that I'm not there yet and there is indeed still something pathological. I'm running a test with a couple of large documents (34MB and 14MB) and it is still taking what seems to be too long a time. I wanted  to test XPath from Saxonica but 'pip install saxonpy' gives me:  

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement saxonpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for saxonpy

Comment: Hi @jfontana the SaxonC on pypy is distributed by third party so we have no control over fixing the installation issues. We will be distributing an official version in the near future. However you can download SaxonC from the Saxonica website and build the python extension by following the instructions on the website.

Comment: @ond1, what timeline is "near future" in terms of a SaxonC releases? 11.5? 12.0?

Comment: Hi @martin-honnen, The plan is to wait for SaxonC 12 to release it on pypy. Probably in a couple of months I hope.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with variable naming since `root` variable has 2 meanings in the code which could cause a [memory problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25126746/2834978).
Given the example below

```
>>> t = os.walk('/home/lmc/tmp/a')
>>> for root, dirs, files in t:
...     print(root)
...     root= uuid.uuid4()
...     print(root)
... 
/home/lmc/tmp/a
ab5839a8-43b5-4d9d-bbb3-4836c612abaf
/home/lmc/tmp/a/b
7a8ba22e-7a02-45d6-82ce-538e11b70e7d
/home/lmc/tmp/a/b/c
de7c0e08-edc4-43e6-9bc1-9b1d7dd7e9db
/home/lmc/tmp/a/b/c/f
2536e2dc-11d1-4b41-86fd-128c3eeaddbc
/home/lmc/tmp/a/b/c/f/g
7d7e61b0-31d4-4af4-9097-540fc2bbac1c
/home/lmc/tmp/a/b/d
1a671eb2-7efe-4dc4-891b-94d1710ef638
/home/lmc/tmp/a/b/d/e
420d5228-44f1-493d-9dae-e2005c4e0f61
```

So instead of a directory name `root` might be holding an xml element on each instance of that list.
Removing withespace from parsed tree could also reduce the  number of nodes in the tree

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):

    # iterate all files
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(ext):
            # join root dir and file name
            file_path = os.path.join(ROOT, file)

            # load root element from file
            parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
            root_ele = et.parse(file_path, parser).getroot()

            # recursively change  elements from xml
            xml_change(root_ele)
```

Finally, as suggested, changing the xpath search strategy also makes a difference

`for el in root.xpath('//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "N")]/preceding-sibling::tok[1]'):`

Comment: Your suggestions once again improved things considerably. Processing the 10,8MB XML file that at the beginning was taking 21 minutes and with the change in the Xpath was taking 3,6 minutes now takes only 1 minute to process. I think there is still a problem for larger files still take too long to process. I finally managed to profile the script and have the results. Alas, I don't know how to interpret them. What should I be looking for? I don't see any way of attaching them here and the comment window is very limited.

Comment: Ran 'python -m cProfile TEST_LXML.py' the parts that are more noticeable are:  
  
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     11/1    0.000    0.000    0.060    0.060 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1002(_find_and_load)
        
[...]  
  
    6  274.218   45.703  274.218   45.703 TEST_LXML.py:14(xml_change)
        1    0.397    0.397  274.676  274.676 TEST_LXML.py:2(<module>)  
  [...]

     5/1    0.000    0.000  274.676  274.676 {built-in method builtins.exec}
       65    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}

Comment: Sorry, the formatting recommendations for the comments [Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) don't seem to work for me. Ending a line with two spaces doesn't give me a new line. This makes it difficult to read the output of the profiling.

Comment: I'd look for longest process calls and see what can be improved there. Xpath can be slow for big files with many nodes since the whole tree is built at parse I believe so for those it's perhaps faster to use `iterparse`. Also look for memory/garbage collection problems. Finally, over optimization can be a problem itself and a compromise solution might be accepted.